# Getting error while assertion Expected: iterable containing ["IT"] Actual: IT

Tags: rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using cucumber to define my test script and in one of my test steps is below
**And response Get Countries and Cities names
|Response.Data["countries_and_cities_names "][0].language_code  | IT |
**

## glue code behind is

```
@And("response Get Countries and Cities names")
public void response_Get_Countries_and_Cities_names(Map < String, String > responseFields)
{
    for (Map.Entry < String, String > field : responseFields.entrySet()) {
        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(field.getValue())) {
            json.body(field.getKey(),
                containsInAnyOrder(Integer.parseInt(field.getValue())));
        }
        else {
            json.body(field.getKey(), containsInAnyOrder(String.valueOf(field.getValue())));
        }
    }
}
```

## Error msg :

JSON path Response.Data["countries_and_cities_names "][0].language_code doesn't match. Expected: iterable containing ["IT"]
               Actual: IT

Can anyone help me to match the both the string?

Comment: Can you share the sample json reponse where you get the IT for the language_code

Comment: This was resolver if we use "is" instead of "containsInAnyOrder".